# How can i handle the CannotAcquireLockException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute query**

*When processing multiple file within 100 nanoseconds the above exception is throwing. how can i handle this case ?*

Comment: Could you please provide what you have done so far? What is the code snippet resulting in this exception and how are you running it?

Comment: Basically the core part of our application is event mechanism and the sftp. Also in some we need some file for further processing and after downloading the file we are storing those file and its contents in table. i think this case is due to database lock. 

Am i correct ? if i am wrong how can i identify the issue ?

Please suggest me some of the case when throwing this exception and handling those case also.

Comment: I guess you should have a look to the HTA guidlines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without enough details, with code source, no one would be able to provide a one-answer-that-fit-it-all.